# Enable/Disable Spell Check in Ckeditor (SCAYT) dynamically

Tags: ckeditor, spell-checking

I'm using SCAYT plugin for ckeditor with multiple languages.I have enabled scayt automatically on startup. via code I want to disable spell check when the user chooses language as Chinese/Japanese in the dropdown through the code. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`editor.execCommand`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-execCommand) to do enable/disable SCAYT manually (via code):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.execCommand( 'scaytcheck' );
```

If you want to decide whether to enable SCAT or not on the startup, use [`pluginsLoaded`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-pluginsLoaded) event to override the config option (see: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/ePC8j/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar,scayt',
    // Turn on SCAYT automatically
    scayt_autoStartup: true,
    on: {
        configLoaded: function() {
            // Disable SCAYT when japanese.
            if ( this.config.language == 'ja' )
                this.config.scayt_autoStartup = false;
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to post what I had found because I didn't find anywhere in the forums that had the answer to the question "How do I enable/disable SCAYT dynamically?". This is how you can do it:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editorId_1.getCommand('scaytcheck').exec()
```

This will run the command that gets called when clicking the "Enable/Disable" button.

Answer (score 1):

As an update to this answer: I'm running CKEditor 4.6 and could only get this working with

```
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].execCommand('scaytToggle');
```

So to iterate through all editors and toggle the scyat:

```
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].execCommand('scaytToggle');
    }
```